# How do I move the contents of one table to another in phpmyadmin? (same database)

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want to move the contents of one table to another in the same database. Is this possible? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Did you tried export to a sql file then import changing table name ?

Comment: No, but I just got it working thanks to your hint. If you enter it as an answer, I'll select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **exporting** to a SQL file then change the table name and **import** it. The two tables have to be the same name.

Answer (score 2):

select table, use Operations tab and copy the table in same database with different name.